# Play mocking web service behind a proxy

Tags: scala, playframework, proxy

I'm using the Play framework 2.5.  I created a new project and tried testing web service.

For the moment I just copied the example at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWebServiceClients#testing-a-github-client .

On my machine I'm using a proxy, and when running GitHubClientSpec

```
testOnly GitHubClientSpec
```

I get an error from the proxy as response.

What I also tried from the scala console is the piece of code :

```
import play.core.server._
import play.api.routing.sird._
import play.api.mvc._

val server = NettyServer.fromRouter(ServerConfig(
  port = Some(19000),
  address = "127.0.0.1"
)) {
  case GET(p"/hello") => Action {
    Results.Ok(s"Hello")
  }
}
```

And `curl http://localhost:19000/hello`, returned "Hello".
So this works fine, but when running `testOnly GitHubClientSpec` it is not.

How to prevent Play from using the proxy ?

Comment: Have you resolved that problem?

Comment: Yes I didn't solve anything, but after launching a new shell and start writing the code again from scratch it was working...